# Need SQL query for the requirement

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables `table1` and `table2` as shown here, and the desired output as below

Table 1:

```
material_num | product_id
-------------+-------------
ABCDE          NULL
THEJR          1ERT34
GTHUJ          23UJ45
HYUIJ          E9JLK5
DFOMC          NULL
```

Table 2:

```
item_number | material_number | id
------------+-----------------+-------
2003          DFOMC             3456
2005          ABCDE             5678
3456          GTHUJ             4857
4003          THEJR             8904
5678          HYUIJ             2002
```

Expected output:

```
material_number | product_id
----------------+-------------
ABCDE             E9JLK5
THEJR             1ERT34
GTHUJ             23UJ45
HYUIJ             E9JLK5
DFOMC             23UJ45
```

I want to derive the `product_id` of the `material_numbers` whose value is null.

The `product_id` can be derived from the `table2` where `ID` of one `material_number = item_number` of another `material_number`, if we found such material number then the product id of such material number will be product if of the material number whose value is null.

**Example:** the id of `material_number` ABCDE is 5678, which is the `item_number` of `material_number` HYUIJ.

So the `product_id` of HYUIJ becomes the `product_id` of ABCDE as well.

I have tried this below query

```
select 
    material_number 
from 
    (select material_number 
     from table2 
     where item_number in (select id from table2)
    ) as material_product_id;
```

Please help to advise on this situation.

Comment: I have tried to join the 2 tables and get the material numbers whose ID and item_number are same in table 2.

Comment: What to do if a id matches multiple rows having the same item_number, what to do if it matches none, what to do if the product_id is not null, but empty? This is very bad DB structure and will lead to very risky queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.
if a value is NULL, I use a subquery to find the corresponding value.

```
SELECT 
    a.material_num,
    -- if product_id is null, search in table2 with id->item_number for material_number
    CASE 
        WHEN a.product_id IS NULL
            THEN (
                    SELECT b.material_number
                    FROM TABLE2 c
                    JOIN TABLE2 b ON c.id = b.item_number
                    WHERE c.material_number = a.material_num
                    )
        ELSE a.product_id
    END AS product_id
FROM TABLE1 a
```

Comment: This will be very slow because it will execute each time the subquery when a null value was found. So if the entire table contains 1000 rows with null, the subquery will also be executed 1000 times. Better execute it once only. You should also not use meaningless table alias like a,b,c, use meaningful alias instead.